# Asymptotic stability of an equilibrium solution of an autonomous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I'm having trouble understanding how I would prove the asymptotic stability of an equilibrium solution for the following problem. I understand what stability is and how to show it with other functions. However, I'm having trouble doing it with this specific function:

$$dy/dt=r(1-y/K)y-Ey$$ where the equilibrium solutions are

$$ Y_1=0,\quad  Y_2=K(1-E/R) > 0 $$ and it is also given that ${E <  r}$

I have proven both equilbrium solutions thus far. I also know that I can treat the original function as F(y) and then take $f'(y)=F'(y)f(y)$ since $f(y)$ = $dy/dt$ and I can use f(y) and f'(y) to sketch a solution family.  At least, I know I should be able to do those things.  For some reason I just don't see the solution here (*bad pun completely intended*).

Can anyone help me out here? If anyone needs additional information please leave a comment. I'm just not sure what all a person might need to help guide someone through such a problem.

Comment: So, what method do you normally use to show stability of equilibrium of $y'=f(y)$? I know two: (i) check that $f<0$ to the right of equilibrium, and $f>0$ to the left; (ii) check that $f'<0$ at the equilibrium (which implies property (i)).

Comment: It seems, thinking intuitively, that 0 must be an obviously unstable equilibrium solution, since any perturbation from 0 causes the solution curve to diverge from 0. Since there are only two equilibriums, and since this is a function used to model population dynamics, I must assume that the second equilibrium point is our carrying capacity.  Thus, it must be asymptotically stable, since a population above or below will tend toward it. However, i'm not sure how to prove this here mathematically.

Comment: I just gave you two ways to prove that mathematically. What do you think of them?

Comment: I think they make sense. I'm just not sure how to apply it here. I just don't see it, for some reason. I should add we have only made judgements about stability by graphing solutions and evaluating behavior of solution curves on either side of the equilibrium point. So, we have done visually what you suggested I do, it seems. I just don't know how to do it with this particular equilibrium point. Maybe the variable salad is throwing me off? Out of curiosity, can you do this by evaluating the limit of the solution curve?

Comment: Solving an equation explicitly (for general initial conditions) just to find out the stability of its equilibrium is rather inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard method to determine the asymptotic stability of an equilibrium $y_*$ of an autonomous ODE $y'=f(y)$ is to compute $f'(y_*)$.

- If $f'(y_*)<0$, the equilibrium is asymptotically stable
- If $f'(y_*)>0$, the equilibrium is unstable
- If $f'(y_*)=0$, further considerations are needed.  Such further considerations involve the sign of $f$ on both sides of equilibrium. If it changes sign from negative to positive, the equilibrium is unstable. If from positive to negative, it is asymptotically stable. If it has the same sign on both sides, we have some sort of semi-stable equilibrium.

Some online resources that expand on this:

- [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EquilibriumSolutions.aspx)
- [Equilibrium: Stable or Unstable?](https://home.comcast.net/~sharov/PopEcol/lec9/equilib.html)

In your case, $f(y) = r(1-y/K)y-Ey$. Hence, 
$$f'(y) = r(1-y/K) - ry/K - E$$
Plug equilibrium value into $f'$, and determine the sign.

Comment: Where could I find a proof for the first two points?