# Semi-stable Equilibrium Solution Initial Value Issue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a differential equation is $\frac{dy}{dt} = k(1-y)^2$ for $k>0$, the equilibrium solution is where $\frac{dy}{dt}=0 \implies y=1$. It is also true that $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$ always, which means we have a semi-stable equilibrium solution. By definition this means that if the initial value $y(0)=y_0$ is below $1$ then the solution should converge to $1$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, and if the initial value is above $1$ then the solution should diverge to $\infty$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

However, the solution to the differential equation with initial condition $y(0)=y_0$ is

$y(t) = \frac{y_0+kt(1-y_0)}{1+kt(1-y_0)}$ or $y(t)=1-\frac{1}{kt+\frac{1}{1-y_0}}$.

They are the same solution just simplified differently.

My problem is that as $t\rightarrow\infty$, $y(t)\rightarrow 1$ regardless of the value of $y_0$. Could someone please explain why this is so? The definition of semi-stable specifically says that the convergence to the equilibrium solutions depends on $y_0$ although it obviously doesn't in this case. Thank you!

Comment: The direction plot clearly shows the semi-stable equilibrium solution at $y=1$. That is the problem. The solution to the differential equation doesn't match this semi-stability. Regardless of the initial value $y_0$, as $t\rightarrow\infty$, $y(t)\rightarrow1$. This is clear in the plots of $y(t)$.

Comment: Plotting $\frac{4-3x}{1-3x}$ similarly yields a function that when $t\rightarrow\infty$, $y(t)\rightarrow1$. This is a problem because according to the definition of semi-stability in this case, $y(t)$ should diverge to $\infty$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.The equilibrium $y=1$ is a horizontal line so I don't understand what you mean by the right and left of it. I think maybe you're trying to say as $t\rightarrow \frac{3}{4}^-$ then $y(t)\rightarrow\infty$? But I don't know why that limit is significant or why anyone would take it with regard to the equilibrium solution.

Comment: Yes I see that the plot of $y(t)$ basically looks like taking the above equilibrium (divergent) piece and putting it to the left side of the below equilibrium (convergent) piece. Why is this significant? Why does it matter if $y\rightarrow\infty$ as $t\rightarrow\frac{3}{4}^-$? I haven't found any references to this limit in my search. This is not helping me reconcile the conflict with the definition of a semi-stable equilibrium, which should hold regardless of the plots. Again, just look at the solution -- regardless of $y_0$ then as $t\rightarrow\infty$ we have $y(t)\rightarrow1$.

Answer (score 1):

Citation :

if the initial value is above $1$ then the solution should diverge to $\infty$ 
as $t\to\infty$ .

This isn't always true because the solution might diverge to $\infty$ 
as $t$ tends to a finite value, say $t_m$. This is the present case :
$$ y(t) = \frac{y_0+kt(1-y_0)}{1+kt(1-y_0)}$$
$$t_m=\frac{1}{k(y_0-1)}$$
A sketch is shown below :

[image]

Comment: Could you pass along the book or article this comes from? I checked several references and all only give the "as $t\rightarrow\infty$" definition. Why would all of them leave out this key piece of information that directly contradicts their definition?

Comment: This is obvious. "as $t\to\infty$" is valid if the function is increasing continuously (without discontinuity) and if there is no other equilibrium point at higher $y$ (it would be an asymptotic semi-stability).

Comment: Is it obvious (haha)? I can't find a single reference pointing to this $t\rightarrow t_m$ limit if $y_0$ is above the equilibrium. Your reasoning and plot makes sense though. I feel like this is in direct contradiction of the "definition" of semi-stability provided by many references though, no? What's with that?

Comment: This isn't specified in the definition of semi-stable equilibrium. As well it isn't specified that the function must diverge when $t\to \infty$. It is only specified $\frac{dy}{dt}>0 above and below the equilibrium point. No more. The divergence at infinity isn't a specification, but a consequence (of course in some cases, but not in all cases).

Comment: For example, see the answer of user147263 in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930256/asymptotic-stability-of-an-equilibrium-solution-of-an-autonomous-differential-eq