# Stability of an equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I would like to determine the stability of equilibrium point $x=0$ of the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x-\sqrt{x}, \\ x(t) > 0$$
By the standard testing procedure, I calculated $f'(x)$ as $1-\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Plugging $x=0$ into the $f'(x)$ gives $f'(0)=1>0$. Then we have $x=0$ is unstable.

However, when I plot the slope field of the DE.
[image]

I found that the trajectories are actually approaching $x=0$. Why?

Comment: I think you have miscalculated the derivative

Comment: As a Bernoulli equation, using $x=u^2$ results in a linear first order ODE $2u'=u-1$ for $u> 0$ from where you can get explicit solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to calculate $f'(t)$, you already have this expression given by the differential equation. Since, this system is time invariant, you just need to calculate $x-\sqrt{x}=0$, which has solutions at $1$ and $0$, as you can see from your plot. 

Because $x-\sqrt x$ will be negative between $0$ and $1$, and positive afterwards, it follows that the trajectories will approach zero from above and diverge away from one. This is again confirmed by your plot. 

You can plot $x-\sqrt x$ and see what values the derivative is going to take. If it is negative, the derivative will be negative and so the trajectories will be directed downward, it it is positive, they will be going upward. At the zeroes of this function, you will have the equilibrium points, and by looking at the plot's negative and positive values, you can tell the nature of the trajectories.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/930312
My calculation is from this answer

Comment: @IDontKnowMath yes, but in this case, the derivative is $1-\frac 12 x^{-1/2}$, which is undefined at $0$. You forgot to subtract one from the exponent when using the power rule. Also, $x-\sqrt x$ is undefined on $x<0$, so to find the behavior of solutions you need to constraint yourself to $0<x$